# convert time in php

Tags: php, date, time

I have the data `2013-02-04 03:20:00`

How do I arrive into this `07:20` using php.

Same is through with this `2013-02-04 08:00:00` to this `12:00`

I have this data labeled timestamp_diff which is `14400`

Any idea? Thank You

I think the answer was base on the timestamp_diff not just adding 4 or any values to it.

Is there any `datetime()` function(s) to get the equivalent of `14400` to `4`

Comment: Be more specific and give some more informations. Provide some code what have you tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <?php

     $add4hour = time() + (4*60*60);

     $newTime = date("d m Y H:i:s",$add4hour);

     echo $newTime;

   ?>
```

Edit because of your requirements

```
 <?php
   $add4hour = time() + (4*60*60); // 4 hour adding
   $d1 = date("d-m-Y H:i:s"); // date 1 assume that hour 03:20:00
   $d2 = date("d-m-Y H:i:s",$add4hour); // date 2, Assume that hour 07:20:00 by adding 4hour
   $d1_timestamp = strtotime($d1); // first date's timestamp
   $d2_timestamp = strtotime($d2); // second date's timestamp
   $time_diff = $d2_timestamp - $d1_timestamp; //difference
   echo $time_diff; // this will give you 14400
  ?>
```

Comment: ah that is how to arrive in `14400`, how to get the `7:20` then

Comment: edited again , you can see the explanation on the php comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$addhr= 4;//Replace you value to be added here
$format="H:i";
echo $date."<br>";
echo date($format, strtotime("$date + $addhr hours"));
```

Comment: what if I do not know the hours to be add, i mean a dynamic code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [\DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and add any interval with [DateTime::add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php). Also you can use procedure style.